# Spring upload form optional with optional file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

We are creating a profile page with a form that optionally has a profile pic on it.  We are using Spring 3.2

Here is the form: -

```
<form:form id="editMember" modelAttribute="memberAjaxEditModel"
    method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    ...
    <form:input path="fileData" type="file"/>
    ...
</form>
```

Here is the controller method: -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onEditPost(@PathVariable long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute(MemberAjaxEditModel.KEY) MemberAjaxEditModel model, BindingResult result) throws ServiceRecoverableException {
....
}
```

Here is the Model

```
public class MemberAjaxEditModel {

...
private CommonsMultipartFile fileData;
...
}
```

It works fine if a file is submitted on the form, but there are errors in the BindingResult variable if the form is submitted without a file.

Here is the error: -

```
Field error in object 'memberAjaxEditModel' on field 'fileData': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.memberAjaxEditModel.fileData,typeMismatch.fileData,typeMismatch.org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [memberAjaxEditModel.fileData,fileData]; arguments []; default message [fileData]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' for property 'fileData'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] for property 'fileData': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out it was the [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) which was sending an empty string instead of what spring expects - nothing to be sent.

I solved the problem using a before submit to remove the fileData value if it wasn't populated like so: -

```
 function beforeSubmit(arr, $form, options){
     var fileDataIndex = -1;

     $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
          if (value.name == "fileData"){
              if (value.value.length == 0){
                  fileDataIndex = index;
              }
          }
        });

     if (fileDataIndex != -1){
        arr.remove(fileDataIndex);
     }
 }
```

I hope this helps some googlers with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ash,I was facing same problem.. it really helped me.. Just that I used arr.splice(fileDataIndex,1); instead of arr.remove(fileDataIndex);

Comment: It works form me too but when I use your method in the option beforeSubmit, the web page is reloaded with the content of the response (I lose the AJAX behavior)...

Comment: I dont really know why but by using Saurabh modification, my problem is gone. Thanks

Comment: @AshMcConnell I am having the same problem. Can you explain the three parameters of beforeSubmit method?

Answer (score 2):

See also [github issue 296](https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/296):

> You can use the iframe option to force the same type of post for both cases:
>
> iframe: true

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `StringMultipartFileEditor`.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringMultipartFileEditor());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` instead of CommonsMultipartFile

Comment: What happens when you remove "@PathVariable long id" from your onEditPost() method (and put it into MemberAjaxEditModel)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `multipartResolver` bean defined in your `application-context.xml` ? If not then include this and try

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"> 
       <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/> <!-- File size in bytes. -->
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already had this (as an @Configuraton class).  It turns out it was the AjaxForm plugin which was sending an empty string instead of what spring expects - nothing to be sent.